# SQL Group by with concat

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000, group-by, concatenation

Hi
Can anybody help me with the following. I need to write a MS SQL statment to achive the following:

Table1 has 2 columns: `Column1` and `Column2`

Data in table1 looks like

```
Column1   Column2
1         a
1         b
1         c
2         w
2         e
3         x
```

I need my Sql statment to output as following

```
Column1   Column2
1         a, b, c
2         w, e
3         x
```

So in other words I need to group by column1 and have the column2 values concatenate with comma seperated. Please note this will need to be able to run on SQL Server 2000 and above

Comment: sorry i was trying to show the sample table with the two columns (Column1 and Column2), not sure why it didnt turn out properly

Comment: Indent each line 4 spaces and it will line up.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a function to concat the values

```
create function dbo.concatTable1(@column1 int) returns varchar(8000)
as
begin
declare @output varchar(8000)
select @output = coalesce(@output + ', ', '') + column2
from table1
where column1 = @column1 and column2 > ''
return @output
end
GO
```

So assuming you had this table

```
create table table1 (column1 int, column2 varchar(10))
insert table1 select 1, 'a'
insert table1 select 1, 'b'
insert table1 select 1, 'c'
insert table1 select 2, 'w'
insert table1 select 2, 'e'
insert table1 select 3, 'x'
GO
```

You use it like this

```
select column1, dbo.concatTable1(column1) column2
from table1
group by column1
```