# Is there a code for concactenantion in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a record in the database:

```
Column1          Column2

    1               a
    1               b
    1               c
```

and the result would be:

```
Column1           Result

    1              abc
```

i just want this query so that i would not use loop :)

Comment: it seems you use SQLServer. So it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894095/sql-group-by-with-concat and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941103/concat-groups-in-sql-server

Comment: @bluish: im using mssql server 2005

Comment: Did either of the posts referenced in @bluish's comment answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MS SQL you could use:

```
Declare @result varchar(1000)
Set @Result = ''

Select 
         @result = (@result  + Column2)

From MyTable
Where Column1 = 1


Select @Result
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate concatenation is not part of the SQL standard for aggregates (`SUM, COUNT, AVG, MIN, MAX, LAST, FIRST`), so if your DBMS has no such function, you should probably define a new [aggregate function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function).

[PostgreSQL documentation offers a nice tutorial on the subject](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-createaggregate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL has no `CONCATENATE` set function by design because all SQL data types are scalar.

Answer (score -4):

if you use MySQL or Oracle, you can use:

> SELECT CONCAT(col1,col2) FROM
>   YOURTABLE

Comment: That's all well and good if he wanted to concat 2 columns, but he wants to concat values in one column depending on another columns value.